# Woocommerce HTML2PDF send pdf

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, html2pdf

I've create a website for selling training. After buying,I would like to send a notification to the customer who ordering the product.
So, i choose to use HTML2PDF to create a dynamic pdf, with a plugin.
But i failed to link the pdf to the mail invoice. Nevertheless the billing form work fine

I use the hook to add the pdf to grap the email after processing order. The submition

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;


add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10,  3);

function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments, $status ,  $order ) {

    $allowed_statuses = array('customer_processing_order');
    if( isset( $status ) && in_array ( $status, $allowed_statuses ) ) {
        $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
        $html2pdf->writeHTML('<h1>HelloWorld</h1>This is my first test');

        $files=$html2pdf->output('convocation.pdf','S');
        $attachments[] = $files;
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```

Thanks for yours reply

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258353/woocommerce-email-attachments-filter-arguments), it looks like instead of adding the entire PDF to `$attachments` as a string, you should add the file path. [`$html2pdf->output`](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/output.md) will save the PDF to the server when second argument is the character 'F', and then after saving it, you'll be able to include the file path to the file in your `$attachments` variable.

So you want something like this. I haven't tested this code.

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;


add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10,  3);

function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments, $status ,  $order ) {

    $allowed_statuses = array('customer_processing_order');
    if( isset( $status ) && in_array ( $status, $allowed_statuses ) ) {
        $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
        $html2pdf->writeHTML('<h1>HelloWorld</h1>This is my first test');

        $pdf_uploads_dir = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/pdfs/';
        if ( ! is_dir( $pdf_uploads_dir ) ) {
            mkdir( $pdf_uploads_dir, 0755 );
        }
        $file_path = $pdf_uploads_dir . 'convocation.pdf';
        $files=$html2pdf->output( $file_path, 'F' );
        $attachments[] = $files;
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```

Comment: The code you wright below create a folder to store the pdf , that right ? I my case i don't create this, just generate the file -> pass the data -> send with the invoice

Comment: I have an other question where is the file store by html2pdf ?

Comment: That's the problem. The `woocommerce_email_attachments` filter needs a file path. You can't pass the data, you have to pass a file path. `$html2pdf->output( $file_path, 'F' )` will store the file at whatever file path you give it. 

As for your second question. I'm using a folder called 'pdfs' inside of the WordPress uploads directory. If this directory doesn't exist, then I create it. But you could store the PDFs somewhere else if you wanted.